# Navigate and interchange form contents between 2 pages without webserver

Tags: html

I am new to html coding and trying to explore html without any webservers help.

I have 2 html pages placed in a directory named 1.html and 2.html

1.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="2.html" method="POST">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Upon click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to 2.html".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

and
2.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="1.html" method="POST">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById('firstname').value =
"Here I need firstname from 1.html";
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I need to know, what mechanism can I use to transfer data from 1.html into 2.html without using any webserver.

means,

if I need to display firstname from 1.html into 2.html,

undersection

```
<script>
document.getElementById('firstname').value =
"Here I need firstname from 1.html";
</script>
```

what code should I write?

Comment: Have you tried local storages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

> 1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<form action="2.html" method="GET">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey" >
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse" >
  <br><br>
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit" >
</form>

<p>Upon click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to 2.html".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

> 2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="2.html" method="GET">
      First name:<br>
      <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="">
      <br>
      Last name:<br>
      <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
      var vars = query.split("&");
      var pair ="";
      for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           pair = pair + vars[i].split("=")+",";
      } 

      var arr=pair.split(",");
      document.getElementById('firstname').value = arr[1];    
      document.getElementById('lastname').value = arr[3];
    };
</script>
```